# Kotlin cancel coroutine in runBlocking()

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

How can I do like that? I need continue work chunk code when job did stop. For example. I've code:

```
private fun method() {
    val a = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
       test()
    }
}

private test() = runBlocking {
    while(isActive) {
      log("Begin work")
      log("JOB "a" in method() did cancel!")
      log("BUT! Here executing more...")
      log("Now. When end loop and second check expression isActive it must be FALSE")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return a value in your `test()` function. For example:

```
fun test(){
        val isActive = false
        repeat(5){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
            Log.d("***", "Delay: $it")
        }

        val result = runBlocking {
            while(isActive) {
                delay(500)
            }
        }
        UtilsLog.write("***", "FINISHED")
    }
```

And here's the log output:

```
2022-08-22 02:21:53.927 11710-11757/com.my.app D/***: Delay: 0
2022-08-22 02:21:54.934 11710-11757/com.my.app D/***: Delay: 1
2022-08-22 02:21:55.942 11710-11757/com.my.app D/***: Delay: 2
2022-08-22 02:21:56.949 11710-11757/com.my.app D/***: Delay: 3
2022-08-22 02:21:57.952 11710-11757/com.my.app D/***: Delay: 4
2022-08-22 02:21:57.953 11710-11757/com.my.app D/***: FINISHED
```

As you can see, `isActive` is controlled outside `withContext{}`, and withContext{} finishes 5 seconds after it was started

Comment: No. If I did cancel Job where I called test() property isActive always is true.

Comment: In that case, something is wrong with your other code (probably wherever you modify isActive). I've updated my answer to show my test run results, and everything works exactly as it should